# Setting sub domain DNS to route default port 80 to custom port

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, port, dns-zone

I have a subdomain let say `work.example.com` 
also I have a server with a public IP let say 192.0.2.4.

I have an application on my server that running on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on port 8088, so this is became 192.0.2.4:8088.

My question is, I want if user open url http://work.example.com on their browser,
this is point to 192.0.2.4:8088.

I've been add SRV configuration on DNS Zone Editor on my domain and it doesn't work, an A record also not possible to use port after an IP.
The reason I do this is, user hard to remember IP or type port after domain name.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For general HTTP purposes (web browsing, etc.), DNS cannot be used to direct a browser to use a specific port.  Browsers are hard-codes to assume 80 for HTTP and 443 for HTTPS.

You "could" host another web site on that sub domain that just does a redirect to the target site and port.

Comment: A reverse proxy would probably be easier.